# SignalR Desktop Client not recieving data send from server

Tags: c#, signalr

MVC5 application using SignalR that sends messages to web clients without an issue.

I now need these messages to also be broadcasted to a desktop application.
Here is what I'm currently trying from the WPF app.

```
private HubConnection hubConnection = null;
private IHubProxy hubProxy = null;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    try
    {
        hubConnection = new HubConnection("https://noccommand/signalr", useDefaultUrl: false);

        hubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("DashboardHub");

        hubProxy.On<List<MetricAlert>>("refreshData", (data) => ProcessData(data));
        hubConnection.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
        hubConnection.Start().Wait();

        //Shows connected
        MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show(hubConnection.State.ToString(), "SignalR", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}


public void ProcessData(List<MetricAlert> data)
{
    MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("WE GOT DATA!", "SignalR", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
}
```

}

Comment: What happens when you run your code?

Comment: Please learn first how to consume async API in WPF/WinForms. You are supposed to call such in the form load event, and mark the event handler as `async` (so that you can await on the API). Your current code looks dangerous (I don't think the constructor exits), so not surprised if it does not work.

Answer (score 2):

Well despite the down votes. I have it working.

I turned on SignalR logging in the WPF application and found the following line to be the issue:

```
 hubProxy.On<List<MetricAlert>>("refreshData", (data) => ProcessData(data));
```

In the error logs it shows it trying to convert a string to the object. I needed to except it as a string and the deserialize the json into the object.